# How to get unmapped row from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am facing problem in SQL Query

I have two tables :

table one

```
ID Number
1  100
2  200
3  300
4  400
5  500
6  600
7  700
8  800
9  900
```

table two

```
ID Someotherdata
1  100
2  200
3  300
4  400
5  500
```

---

I tried a query

```
Select one.ID,one.Number
from table1 one
Left Outer Join
table2 two
on one.ID=two.id
```

I want the result

```
6  600
7  700
8  800
9  900
```

Comment: Are you after results that don't appear in both tables? Or just ones from table one that don't appear in table 2?

Answer (score 1):

Use `except` :

```
Select one.ID,one.Number
from table1 one
except
(Select one.ID,one.Number
from table1 one
inner join
table2 two
on one.ID=two.id)
```

**[SQL Fiidle to test](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3fc9a/4)**

**Edit (On OP request)**

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.number FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 on table2.id = table1.id
WHERE table2.id  IS NULL
```

**[Here is the SQL Fiidle for Testing](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3fc9a/2)**

Comment: Guys I am thinking something like self join please help me on that

Comment: @VSS-TFS-CSharp You should respond to my comment above. Would help identify what you are truly after.

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you have two tables with corresponding IDs. Not all entries in `table1` is in `table2`, but those entries present in `table2` has the same ID as that of `table1`.

This should work:

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.number FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.id
WHERE table2.id IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select one.ID,one.Number
from table1 one
Where not in(Select two.ID From Table2 two)
```

Comment: Guys I am thinking something like self join please help me on that